# VueJS modify parent Variable from child

Tags: .net, .net-core, vuejs2

I am quite new to VueJs and thanks for advance for the help.
I am using.NetCore MVC and Vue together. It is not a single page application...

QUESTION:
In my website, I have got a component displays a confirmation modal, In the modal page there is a cancel button and if the user clicks the cancel button, I would like to set modalBox property false in the Parent class.

What I did: This is my component.

```
 Vue.component('modalquestion-box', {
  props: ['modalBox', 'message', 'messagedetail'],
data() {
    return {
        isHidden: true
    }
},
watch: {
    modalBox: function () {           
        if (this.modalBox == true)            
            $('#adjConfirmModal').modal('show');
    }
},
methods: {
    "cancelBtnSelected": function () {
        console.log('Cancel Selected');
        this.modalBox = false;         

    }

},
template: `<div class="modal fade" id="adjConfirmModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="adjConfirmModalTitle" aria-hidden="true">
             <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="adjConfirmModalTitle">Confirm</h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>Are you sure ?</p>

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="cancelBtnSelected" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <button type="button" v-on:click="adjConfirmed" class="btn btn-success">Confirm</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
         </div>`
 });
```

**My Layout Page**

```
<modalquestion-box v-bind:modal-box.sync="modalBox" v-bind:message="message" v-bind:messagedetail="messageDetail" v-on:closemessage="modalBox = false"></modalquestion-box>
```

**Main Vue Class - Parent**

```
new Vue({
el: '#app',
mounted: function () {
    this.fetchData();
},
data: {
    message: '',
    messageDetail: '',
    messageBox: false,
    modalBox: false

},
methods: {        
    "showConfirmModal": function () {
        this.modalBox = !this.modalBox ;            
    }


}
```

});

> It is working but i need to click confirm button on parent page twice to show the modal message. the first click sets modalBox to true and it shows the modal, then when i click same button it sets false. then i click one more time to show modal again.

Basically i need to change modalBox property to false when user clicks Cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Subcomponents, use `this.$emit('closemessage')`

```js
<modalquestion-box v-on:closemessage="modalBox = false"></modalquestion-box>

/************** sub *******************/
cancelBtnSelected: function () 
  console.log('Cancel Selected');
  this.modalBox = false;  
  this.$emit('closemessage') // A function that is sent to the parent component binding
}
```

Comment: Thank you Gao but i am getting the same error..... [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value. Prop being mutated: "modalBox"

Comment: Ok I fixed it with removing this.modalBox = false; Thanks a lot Gao

Comment: [Vue warn]: Avoid mutating a prop directly since the value will be overwritten whenever the parent component re-renders. Instead, use a data or computed property based on the prop's value.                 you can  use of a object,     parent :`messageVisible:{bol:false}`,